# Trying to create a rounded corner UIButton class

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I am trying to create a rounded corner UIButton class but it is not working. This is what I have so far:

**interface**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface BotaoCantosArredondados : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat radius;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGSize shadowOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat shadowRadius;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat shadowOpacity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *shadowColor;


@end
```

**implementation**

```
#import "BotaoCantosArredondados.h"
@import QuartzCore;


@interface BotaoCantosArredondados() {
  CALayer *sombraLayer;
}
@end


@implementation BotaoCantosArredondados

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  [super drawRect:rect];

  if (sombraLayer) {
    [sombraLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
  }

  sombraLayer = [CALayer layer];
  sombraLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
  sombraLayer.shadowColor = [_shadowColor CGColor];
  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                                  cornerRadius:_radius];
  path.lineWidth = _shadowRadius;
  sombraLayer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;

  sombraLayer.shadowOffset = _shadowOffset;
  sombraLayer.shadowOpacity = _shadowOpacity;
  sombraLayer.shadowRadius = _radius;
  sombraLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

  [self.layer addSublayer:sombraLayer];

}

- (void)setShadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor {
  _shadowColor = shadowColor;
}

- (void)setShadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset {
  _shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
}

- (void)setShadowRadius:(CGFloat)shadowRadius {
  _shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
}

- (void)setShadowOpacity:(CGFloat)shadowOpacity {
  _shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
}

- (void)setRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
  _radius = radius;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean as "not working"? can you elaborate?

Comment: not working. I change values on interface builder and there is no change on the buttons. I run the project, no button corner or shadow.

Comment: are you imported teh quartz core frame work'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try manipulating the layer of the Button i.e;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface BotaoCantosArredondados : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat radius;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGSize shadowOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat shadowRadius;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat shadowOpacity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *shadowColor;

@end
```

and the implementation;

```
#import "BotaoCantosArredondados.h"

@implementation TestButton

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.clipsToBounds = NO;

    }
    return self; }


- (void)setShadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor {
    _shadowColor = shadowColor;
    self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.CGColor;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)setShadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset {
    _shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)setShadowRadius:(CGFloat)shadowRadius {
    _shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)setShadowOpacity:(CGFloat)shadowOpacity {
    _shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];

}

- (void)setRadius:(CGFloat)radius {
    _radius = radius;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay]; }

@end
```

**Edit :-**  you need to remove assign subclass class , then remove all property manually . and then again assign class to button and then Run programme.

Check this ,

[image]

Output :-

[image]

Comment: your example works for me for the corner radius only but the shadow does not appear.

Comment: sill not working for me. Are you sure this is working for you?

Comment: I think I discovered the problem but I don't know how to solve it. The shadow is being drawn inside the button bounds, being clipped by it. Addding `self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;` makes no difference.

Comment: Updated again with screenshot.

Comment: @cekisakurek sorry i have edited your answer.  i know that sure Spacedog missing this step. so, he will get old output.

Comment: @BadalShah no problem mate. your screenshots are way better than mine :)

Comment: for some strange reason, it is working now but not for buttons of type equal to CUSTOM. Anyway, THANKS!!!!!!!!!